# QuerySelector For Page With Two <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I'm trying to write a querySelector for 'body5' below.

```
document.querySelectorAll("html frameset frameset frame"); //works
document.querySelectorAll("html frameset frameset frame html"); //returns empty node list.
document.querySelectorAll("html frameset frameset frame body5"); //returns empty node list.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <frameset >
   <frameset >
    <frame >
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <body class="body5">
```

The problem seems to be that second html tag, can't seem to get past it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t think this is valid HTML. Have you checked in your browser’s DOM inspector what DOM node structure it _creates+ from this HTML? If the error correction mechanism of the browser did not create DOM nodes according to the HTML tags used, then of course you can not select those elements (simply because they don’t exist …).

Comment: Hmm, yeah I really don't know how to check the DOM. I do automation testing not GUI development :) Anyway the page is a popup. Maybe should have mentioned that before not sure it if matters... And the popup works fine. If I type inputs in the fields in 'body5' data is returned properly. So it appears the page is fine. I just need a query selectory so I can uniquely id the element for input to my automation framework. I have a feeling my querySelector syntax is not good...